# Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://api.example.com does not match any trusted origins.): /admin/login/

Tags: django, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm running a Django app over DigitalOcean's Kubernetes, the site runs over `https` but when I try to use the Django Admin from the domain, it throws a 403 forbidden error but if I connect directly to the Pod it succeeds. I wondered if it has to do with the `ingress` set up that is not recognizing the paths of `api.example.com`.

Here's the `ingress.yaml` file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
      - api.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret-name
  rules:
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 8000
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem. The solution since Django 4.2, is setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")` on your `setting.py` file